# SQL Server store multiple values in sql variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays, variables, stored-procedures

I have the following query:

```
select * 
from cars 
where make in ('BMW', 'Toyota', 'Nissan')
```

What I want to do is store the where parameters in a SQL variable.

Something like:

```
declare @caroptions varchar(max);
select @caroptions =  select distinct(make) from carsforsale;
print @caroptions;
select * from cars where make in (@caroptions)
```

Problem is the print of `@caroptions` only has the last result returned from:

```
select distinct(make) from carsforsale;
```

I want it to store multiple values.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not select it into a table variable or temporary table?

Comment: A **single variable** can only ever hold **a single value**. If you need multiple values, you need to use a **table variable** in SQL Server

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a table variable:

```
declare @caroptions table
(
    car varchar(1000)
)

insert into @caroptions values ('BMW')
insert into @caroptions values ('Toyota')
insert into @caroptions values ('Nissan')

select * from cars where make in (select car from @caroptions)
```

Comment: Seems not much different from "select * from cars where make in ('BMW', 'Toyota', 'Nissan')". But they were put into table variable. This is wasteful, unless using the variable more than once.

Comment: Of course it’s not that much different...but that’s exactly what the OP asked for: “How can I store these parameters in a variable?”

Answer (score 6):

I wrote about this [here](http://sqlstudies.com/2013/04/08/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-an-in-clause/) if you want to see it in detail.  In the mean time, you can't do it exactly how you are thinking.

Your choices are:

Using the LIKE command:

```
DECLARE @CarOptions varchar(100)
SET @CarOptions = 'Ford, Nisan, Toyota'

SELECT *
FROM Cars
WHERE ','+@CarOptions+',' LIKE ',%'+CAST(Make AS varchar)+',%'
```

A spliter function

```
DECLARE @CarOptions varchar(100)
SET @CarOptions = 'Ford, Nisan, Toyota'

SELECT Cars.*
FROM Cars
JOIN DelimitedSplit8K (@CarOptions,',') SplitString
    ON Cars.Make = SplitString.Item
```

Dyanmic SQL

```
DECLARE @CarOptions varchar(100)
SET @CarOptions = 'Ford, Nisan, Toyota'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * ' + 
            'FROM Cars ' + 
            'WHERE Make IN ('+@CarOptions+') '

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

In the mean time your best option is going to be to get rid of the variable completely.

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE make IN (SELECT make FROM carsforsale );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CTE for storing multiple values into a single variable.

```
;WITH DATA1 AS 
(
    select car_name
    from cars 
    where make in ('BMW', 'Toyota', 'Nissan')
)
SELECT @car_name = CONCAT(@car_name,',',car_name)
FROM DATA1

select @car_name
```

Answer (score 1):

why not?

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE make IN (SELECT DISTINCT(make) FROM carsforsale)
```

Comment: Sorry, just an example, not my actual requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Fetch 1 value in table and store in variable    
=======================================================================================

Declare @query int

    select @query = p.ProductID From Product p inner join ReOrdering as r on 
    p.ProductID = r.ProductID and r.MinQty >= p.Qty_Available

    print @query
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JOIN statement.

```
SELECT distinct c.*
FROM cars c
JOIN carsfrosale s
ON s.id = c.fk_s
```

If you want filter your list of carsforsale you can add

```
WHERE s.id in (....)
```

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL you can use STRING_AGG this way

```
select STRING_AGG(car_name,',') as csv
from cars 
where make in ('BMW', 'Toyota', 'Nissan')
```