# How to use a Table Variable with this specific T-SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, table-variable

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I have the following `T-SQL` query running against a table on my database. The query runs fine but my issue is that I want to get an output for several specific dates. Instead of running the query multiple times (by changing the value of the `@Date` variable each time), I would like it to store the `@Date` values somewhere and implement the logic in my Query. How can I do this?

My original Query stands as follows:

```
DECLARE @Date date;
SET @Date = '20180630';

SELECT @Date, COUNT(*) AS Employees
FROM RavEmpID
WHERE DateOfEntry <= @Date
  AND (DateLeft > @Date
   OR  DateLeft IS NULL);
```

From the following post on `StackOverflow` ([SQL Server store multiple values in sql variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745421/sql-server-store-multiple-values-in-sql-variable)), I understand that I need a Table Variable to store the `@Date` values I need.

So, I created a Table Variable (called `TableVariable`) on my database.
The `TableVariable` table has only one column named `Date` as follows:

```
 Date
 2015-11-30
 2015-12-31
 2016-01-31
 2016-02-29
 ...
```

My new `T-SQL` now stands as follows:

```
SELECT b.[Date], COUNT(*) AS Employees

FROM RavEmpID a

left join TableVariable b on b.[Date] = a.[DateLeft]

WHERE a.DateOfEntry <= b.[Date]
  AND (a.DateLeft > b.[Date]
   OR  a.DateLeft IS NULL)

GROUP BY b.[Date]
```

When running this query, I have zero output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think may be the issue lies in the JOIN as there might not be any Dates in the TableVariable which match the DateLeft in the RavEmpID table. If I remove the JOIN, how do I tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few changes to your query:

- Move all your original `WHERE` conditions into the `ON` clause
- Make the date table the *first* table in the `LEFT JOIN` because you want to keep all those dates
- Change the ``COUNT()` so it counts matches

The resulting query:

```
SELECT d.[Date], COUNT(r.DateOfEntry) AS Employees
FROM TableVariable d LEFT JOIN
     RavEmpID r
     ON r.DateOfEntry <= d.[Date] AND
        (r.DateLeft > d.[Date] OR r.DateLeft IS NULL)
GROUP BY d.[Date]
GROUP BY d.[Date];
```

Note that I also changed the table aliases from arbitrary letters to abbreviations for the table names.  That makes the query much easier to read.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Exactly what I needed. I think you need to change the b.[Date] into d.[Date] in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Your join is base on

```
 b.[Date] = a.[DateLeft]
```

But your where clause is base on

```
 a.DateLeft > b.[Date]
```

So there is no logic to get records.
try this:

```
SELECT b.[Date], COUNT(*) AS Employees

FROM RavEmpID a

inner join TableVariable b on b.[Date] = a.[DateLeft]

WHERE a.DateOfEntry <= b.[Date]
```

Comment: It does give me an output for each dates in the TableVariable table but the figures are not correct. In fact, I need it to give me the total number of employees as at the dates in the TableVariable table. For example, for Date 2017-11-30, I need the total number of employees who have not yet left. ie: their DateLeft is > 2017-11-30